# Label color of disabled SwiftUI buttons

Tags: swiftui, uicolor

What are the label colors of these disabled SwiftUI buttons? I would like to use the colors in my own button styles so that they are consistent with the existing styles.

I found that they have some transparency. Also, they are different in light and dark mode. But none of the system colors seems to match. I experimented with transparency, too, without success so far.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Button("Button", action: {})
                .disabled(true)
            Button("Button (same BG as bordered)", action: {})
                .disabled(true)
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
            Button("BorderedButton", action: {})
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .disabled(true)
            // Same with different background
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Button("Button", action: {})
                    .disabled(true)
                Button("Button (same BG as bordered)", action: {})
                    .disabled(true)
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
                Button("BorderedButton", action: {})
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    .disabled(true)
            }.background(Color(.label))
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Light mode:

[image: Light Mode]

Dark mode:

[image: Dark Mode]

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: Hi @Asperi, the question is what is the disabled label color so that I can use it in my own button styles.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just play around with different RGB and opacity values until you find one you want or that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use .opacity(isDisable ? 0.5 : 1) on my button or stack to present disabled buttons. It will give you the disabled effect look and the transparent look too.